# python AsyncHTMLSession: You don't have permission to access "XXX" on this server

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I want to access a site with python using `AsyncHTMLSession` from `requests_html` library.
This is my code:

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
import asyncio

async def connect_to_site(url):
    session = AsyncHTMLSession()
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"}
    res = await session.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(res)
    await res.html.arender(sleep=5, timeout=30)
    print(res.html.full_text)

url = 'https://www.otcmarkets.com'

asyncio.run(connect_to_site(url))
```

After executing the code, I get the following print:

> <Response [200]>
> Access Denied
> Access Denied
> You don't have permission to access "http://www.otcmarkets.com/" on this server.
> Reference #18.9c4519d4.1643149046.338b64e3

What could be the issue? and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's some kind of bot detection. However `requests_html` could render JS, it's not a real browser and can't fully bypass bot protection.

You could use some lib to control real browser like `playwright`/`selenium`/`puppeteer`

Here is the example with `playwright`:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

URL = 'https://www.otcmarkets.com'

with sync_playwright() as p:
    # Webkit is fastest to start and hardest to detect
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=True)

    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(URL)

    html = page.content()

print(html)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though, how fast it is compared to requests? since I would like to make several urls requests at the same time. I have it written in selenium, but it took a lot of time, this is why I moved to requests.

Comment: Speed should be about the same as `requests_html` uses `pyppeteer` and real browser under the hood to render JS. To do multiple requests at same time, loop for async version of playwright, which is able to handle concurrent requests